# What's the scope of definition of "persistent state" in EmberJS?

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js

It may sound like a pedantic question. Sorry :)

I have a case like this... here's my router definition:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('gobernadores', { path: '/gobernadores' }, function() {
    this.resource('gobernador', { path: '/:id_estado' }, function() {
      this.route('simulacion', { path: '/simulacion' }),
      this.route('info', { path: '/info' })
    })
  });
  this.route("login");
  this.route("bienvenido");
});
```

In the "gobernadores" route, I have list of provinces. You can see it's a nested layout. In that same page, we're showing the currently-selected province (that's the gobernador route). Inside the template for that gobernador route, I have a tab, with two elements..., one showing the route "simulacion", and the other one showing the template of route "info" (of that province).

Now, the problem: as user jumps from one province to another province (by clicking the navigation menu on the left side of the screen), I want to keep in memory, the tab that was currently selected, for each province.

So, if the user is currently seeing the result of simulacion of province X, and then he clicks on the link to go to province Y (where he will be presented with "info" of province  Y), and then he goes back to province X, I want the app to take the user back to the screen he was seeing (the simulacion of province X).

You can't have that information stored in the controller (GobernadorController), because I can see that controllers can't keep state, it's stateless.

So..., I have to move that info into the model of the route (GobernadorRouteModel)...

My doubt: is it okay? Why my doubt? Because of this: http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/core-concepts/

It says:

> MODELS
>
> A model is an object that stores persistent state. Templates are
>   responsible for displaying the model to the user by turning it into
>   HTML. In many applications, models are loaded via an HTTP JSON API,
>   although Ember is agnostic to the backend that you choose.
>
> ROUTE
>
> A route is an object that tells the template which model it should
>   display.

This GobernadorRouteModel is not something I persists in the backend. I have no intention to do that. So, am I violating the general advice for a good EmberJS app?

Or in other words: "persistent" here doesn't have to mean "something you save into DB", right? It's just "something you want to keep around..., eventhough only during the session of the app, in the memory".

Thanks in advance,
Raka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can't have that information stored in the controller (GobernadorController), because I can see that controllers can't keep state, it's stateless.

This might be where your problem arises. Controllers are *not* stateless. Controllers in Ember are singletons and keep their state throughout the lifecycle of the app. However, this is going to change in [Ember 2.0](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0015-the-road-to-ember-2-0.md). To quote from that RFC:

> Persistent state should be stored in route objects and passed as initial properties to routable components.

So if you're trying to be forward-compatible, that is the approach I would take. In my opinion, models should really only be used for persistent state (persistent meaning it's persisted between page loads). To keep session state, I would do as the RFC says and keep that state in the routes and inject it into the controllers during the `resetController` hook.

Or if you don't want to be that fancy and you don't care about forward-compatibility, just have a global `Session` object that you store state in. That's how I currently do it and it works quite well. (Although we will probably move away from it.)

TL;DR: No, I don't think you're using models for their intended purpose.

Comment: Oh, I get it... instead of making "selected tab" as a property of the model of the route, I should make that a direct property of the route instead, right?

Comment: Or... like you said, have that mapping (province -> selectedTab) a property of that singleton controller.

Comment: Yes, either of those would work. It seems like the Ember 2.0 way of doing it would be to have the property on the route, then change it using actions.